# Is it possible to build an android app that installs 3 apk, which are stored inside the app itself?

Tags: android

I'm new to android studio and I'm a beginner. I want to build an app that contains 2 or 3 apk files inside the app itself - not in device storage - and make a single button to prompt to install all of them. Is that possible?!

Answer (score 0):

Use this to save file to storage after requesting necessary permission : Write_External_Storage

```
private void copyAsset(String filename){
    String dirPath = 
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/MyFiles";
    File dir = new File(dirPath);
    if(!dir.exists()){
        dir.mkdirs();

    }

    AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
    InputStream in = null;
    OutputStream out = null;
    try {
        in = assetManager.open( filename);
        File outFile = new File(dirPath, filename);
        out = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
        copyFile(in, out);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Saved!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } finally {
        if (in != null){
            try{
                in.close();
            } catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if (out != null){
            try{
                out.close();
            } catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

private void copyFile(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int read;
    while ((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1){
        out.write(buffer, 0, read);

    }
}
```

And finally use this to install:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new 
File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath + "/MyFiles/" + 
"appName.apk")), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

Make sure to request permessions : REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES and READ EXTERNAL STORAGE